# Repetition of same page when printing DataGridView (VB 2010)

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

I'm working on an application to show a Student's print history for work. I am able to pull data into a DataGridView and display it with no problem, but when I go to print the data, it feeds a replication of the first page until it errors out. Single page reports work fine, so I'm thinking this has to be something fairly simple. Here is the section of code where the printing is handled:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    With dgvPrintHistory
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        Dim newpage As Boolean = True
        Dim mRow As Integer = 0
        Dim prFont As New Font("Verdana", 22, GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Dim siFont As New Font("Verdana", 9, GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Dim hdrFont As New Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Dim strStudentInfo As String

        If PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape Then
            strStudentInfo = "Pages Printed (Semester): " & lblPrintPages.Text & vbTab & "Semester Balance: " & lblBalance.Text & vbTab & "Reporting Dates: " & lblDates.Text
            fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(picICC.Image, 130, 10)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(vbTab & "        Student Printing Report: " & lblUserName.Text, prFont, Brushes.Black, 60, 40)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strStudentInfo, siFont, Brushes.Black, 110, 80)
            PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 100
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 100
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 50
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 50
            y = 120
        Else
            strStudentInfo = "Pages Printed (Semester): " & lblPrintPages.Text & vbTab & "Semester Balance: " & lblBalance.Text & vbTab & "Reporting Dates: " & lblDates.Text
            fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(picICC.Image, 90, 10)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(vbTab & "        Student Printing Report: " & lblUserName.Text, prFont, Brushes.Black, 5, 40)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strStudentInfo, siFont, Brushes.Black, 55, 80)
            PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 50
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 50
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 100
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 100
            y = 100
        End If
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0

            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                If newpage Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvPrintHistory.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvPrintHistory.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `e.HasMorePages = False` on the last page. You'll also need to set a module level page counter variable to keep a track of which page you are on. The PrintPage routine only prints a single page. The range of values for your `mRow` variable should be a function of the module level page counter variable.

Comment: I wanted to thank both of you - both of your answers were helpful! I did some restructuring of my code using your suggestions (both SSS and User2095218) and now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim mRow As Integer = 0
 Dim newpage As Boolean = True
```

and `e.HasMorePages = False`

**mRow newpage** and has to be declared outside private sub,

that done and it stops counting pages on the end